# swift ui アラート Type 'CGFloat' has no member 'main'

Tags: swift, swiftui

swift ui で

TextEditor(text: $text)
.frame(width: .main.bounds.width * 0.8, height: 200)

とすると

Type 'CGFloat' has no member 'main'

というアラートが出ます。

その前にはUIScreenを置いていました。

UIKitを付けてもアラートが出ました。

.mainはサポートされていないのですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

frame(width: ?)にはCGFloatが入るので、CGFloatのinit, staticなどであれば`.`始まりでいけますが、今回の場合はCGFloatはmainを持っていないので、`.`始まりは不可能です。

```swift
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8, height: 200)
.frame(width: .zero)
```

無理やりやることも可能ですが、意味がないです。

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text: String = "Hello"
  
  var body: some View {
    TextEditor(text: $text)
      .frame(width: .main.bounds.width * 0.8, height: 200)
  }
}

extension CGFloat {
  static let main: UIScreen = .main
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。